# How could I access localstorage under Python requests

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler, python-requests

I found I need to send a session id `x-connection-id` which is stored by server side  Javascript `localStorage.setItem("x-connection-id")`

If and only if I get this id, so that I can keep going the following request.

Any idea ?

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36',
    'x-connect-id': 'i need it',
}

req.get('https://api.sample/api/v1//flightavailability?'+urllib.parse.urlencode(params))
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like it's impossible

> Local storage is specific to browser.
>
> Local Storage is a way to store persistent data using JavaScript. It
> should be used only with HTML5 compatible web browser.
>
> To access Local storage in python, a compatible browser's python API is required.